# Merging field names in the datagridview

Tags: sql, datagridview, merge, field-names

I want to merge the fieldname in the datagridview which is all text of each field names has combined and make it as one for example:

```
cashierfn: Don
cashiermi: C
cashierln: Lee
```

and combine it as:

```
Cashier Name: Lee, Don C.
```

I made this code to get it:

```
select cashierln, cashierfn, cashierid as 'Cashier Name'
from cashier;
```

And only the cashierid has change its name.
what should I do!
do you have an idea whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select cashierln + ', ' + cashierfn + ' ' + cashiermi + '.' as CashierName
from cashier
```

but it will produce an extra space or a lone dot when middle name is null or empty. So here's a workaround:

```
select cashierln + ', ' + cashierfn + 
    case when cashiermi is null
      then ' ' + cashiermi + '.'
      else ''
    end as CashierName
from cashier
```

Comment: you just rename its field name, I want to merge it as one. but thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: @Spidey: Do you mean this?